# Run a method in each request in MVC, C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In WebForm we could write a method in MasterPage.cs and it ran in each request .
e.g:

```
MasterPage.cs
--------------
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   CheckCookie();
}
```

How can we do something like this in MVC ?

Comment: Maybe this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650269/how-do-i-get-certain-code-to-execute-before-every-single-controller-action-in-as

Comment: You want to put an ActionFilterAttribute on the controller

Comment: I would also look at what the method is doing  and if it is still needed in MVC, no point porting something that new technology makes obsolete.

Comment: @tyrongower: CheckCookie() must check client cookies and it can be access to session !

Comment: I built an ASP.NET Core 2 app, using Razor Pages, Razor Pages, don't a have controller?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

In ASP.NET MVC you could write a [custom global action filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513%28v=vs.98%29.aspx).

---

UPDATE:

As requested in the comments section here's an example of how such filter might look like:

```
public class MyActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var fooCookie = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["foo"];
        // TODO: do something with the foo cookie
    }
}
```

If you want to perform authorization based on the value of the cookie, it would be more correct to implement the [IAuthorizationFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.iauthorizationfilter.aspx) interface:

```
public class MyActionFilterAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var fooCookie = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["foo"];

        if (fooCookie == null || fooCookie.Value != "foo bar")
        {
            filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
        }
    }
}
```

If you want this action filter to run on each request for each controller action you could register it as a global action filter in your global.asax in the `RegisterGlobalFilters` method:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    filters.Add(new MyActionFilterAttribute());
}
```

And if you need this to execute only for particular actions or controllers simply decorate them with this attribute:

```
[MyActionFilter]
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Could you please write a sample for it?

Comment: @Mohammad, sure, I thought you read the article that I have linked to in my answer and tried to implement the sample code shown there. Apparently I was wrong in thinking this. So I have updated my answer to show an example.

Comment: Thanks dude, but a question. how can we redirect to an action in `MyActionFilterAttribute`?

Comment: @Mohammad, by assigning an instance of `RedirectToRouteResult` to the `filterContext.Result` property in your action filter.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: Thanks for very good answer. But how about if I create a class that inherit from controller and check that code in it's constructor and inherit all controller from this new class? Is this a good idea? Thanks

Answer (score 8):

You could use Global.asax `Application_AcquireRequestState` method which will get called on every request:

```
protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //...
}
```

Comment: So, can we access to Cookie and Session from above method ?

Comment: Yes you can. but this method may be execute more than one in per request