# OnInit and Session in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

In ASP.Net, we previously wrote this code for authorization :

```
public class PageBase : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected override void OnInit(System.EventArgs e)
    {
        string CurrentPath = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.ToLower();

        //Check If User Access to this Path
        if(WebUser.Access(CurrentPath) == false)
        {
            Reposponse.Redirect("Loagin.aspx");
        }
    }    
}
```

And `WebUser` is a Session that Contains user data:

```
public User WebUser
{
    get
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session["User"] != null)
        {
            return (User)HttpContext.Current.Session["User"];
        }
        else
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("Login.aspx", true);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

we inherit all page from `PageBase`.

Now if I want to write similar code using `MVC` where I can write a code that run on every request?

Thank

Comment: This looks like a very strange custom authorization system.  But in general if you're just looking to inject custom code into the framework's request/response pipeline then a custom action filter seems like the ideal approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9511462/run-a-method-in-each-request-in-mvc-c  The filter can be applied to specific actions or controllers by way of an attribute, or registered globally to execute on every request.

Comment: Replaced the `C#-7` tag with `C#` as this doesn't seem specific to v7 of the compiler. Please feel free to undo my change if I am wrong in this regard.

Comment: Do not misuse Session State for tracking authentication state! By doing this you are introducing a serious security flaw in your application. There are many secure (pre-built / out of the box) ways to track authentication in an asp.net (including mvc) based application like asp.net-identity to name one.

Comment: @Igor Please explain what security consideration should I attend? You mean sessions aren't secure? What type of attacks may occur for me? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to authenticate and authorize the user in MVC as per your question. You can authenticate and authorize a user using the Authentication and Authorization filters. It is very simple,

- You need to create authentication and authorization filter and
  [image]
- then you need to use that filter on Controller(when validating for all action method mentioned in that controller) or Action method (when validation for only action method) as an attribute.
  [image][image]

Please look the [link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/filters-in-Asp-Net-mvc-5-0-part-twelve/) to check how we can create authentication and authorization filter and how we can use them in code.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a `BaseController` class and apply it to each of your `MVC Controllers`. You could add your universal properties and methods to that:

```
public class ControllerBase : Controller
{
    public string UniversalPath { get; set; }

    public ControllerBase()
    {          
    }
}
```

And then have your `MVC page controllers` inherit from your `BaseController` instead of the default `Controller` class:

```
public class ExamplePageController : ControllerBase
{
    public ActionResult Index(int id)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```